# Master Card 3D-Secure | AUTHENTICATION_PENDING | Status Rejected

Tags: api, mastercard, 3ds

I just followed the MPGS Direct Flow Using Session
What I do. !

1. Create Session
2. Update Session With Card
3. Initiate Authentication
4. Authenticate Payer | Response - AUTHENTICATION_PENDING
5. and then when we hit pay API they will return and rejected

> ```
> {
>    "response":{
>       "gatewayCode":"BLOCKED"
>    },
>    "result":"FAILURE",
>    "risk":{
>       "response":{
>          "gatewayCode":"REJECTED",
>          "review":{
>             "decision":"NOT_REQUIRED",
>             "note":""
>          },
>          "rule":[
>             {
>                "data":"GATEWAY_RECOMMENDS_REJECT",
>                "name":"MSO_3D_SECURE",
>                "recommendation":"REJECT",
>                "type":"MSO_RULE"
>             },
>             {
>                "data":"512345",
>                "name":"MSO_BIN_RANGE",
>                "recommendation":"NO_ACTION",
>                "type":"MSO_RULE"
>             },
>             {
>                "data":"127.0.0.1",
>                "name":"MSO_IP_ADDRESS_RANGE",
>                "recommendation":"NO_ACTION",
>                "type":"MSO_RULE"
>             },
>             {
>                "data":"UK1",
>                "name":"MSO_IP_COUNTRY",
>                "recommendation":"NO_ACTION",
>                "type":"MSO_RULE"
>             }
>          ]
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

authentication result depends on the response that came from the issuer bank and sent to acquirer bank to allow him to proceed with pay operation, pay operation to proceed in MPGS first ProcessACS operation should return AUTHINTACATION_SUCCEESSFULL or at least AUTHENTACATION_ATTEMPTE (certain cases can be accepted based on liability mode) otherwise you get rejected.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply now i get another error from MPGS 
"rule": [
                {
                    "data": "NO_LIABILITY_SHIFT",
                    "name": "MSO_3D_SECURE",
                    "recommendation": "REJECT",
                    "type": "MSO_RULE"
                },
                {
                    "data": "512345",
                    "name": "MSO_BIN_RANGE",
                    "recommendation": "NO_ACTION",
                    "type": "MSO_RULE"
                }
            ]

Comment: Hi Waleed i want to ask if this happens in the production or staging environment also with certain cards issued from the same issuer bank or multiple banks? because I feel that merchant configuration not set properly like in this error issuer bank didn't give permission to MCPGS to proceed with capture fund

Comment: Yes Maybe because when I try directly to create an order from MPGS Development dashboard they will return an error something like contact to MPGS Support

Comment: Hi waleed have you done this? I stuck at initiate authentication. can you guide me a little about this? thanks in advance.